# Semicolon in C++?

Tags: c++, c

Is the "missing semicolon" error really required? Why not treat it as a warning?

When I compile this code

```
int f = 1
int h=2;
```

the compiler intelligently tells me that where I am missing it. But to me it's like - "If you know it, just treat it as if it's there and go ahead. (Later I can fix the warning.)

```
  int sdf = 1, df=2;
  sdf=1 df =2
```

Even for this code, it behaves the same. That is, even if multiple statements (without ;) are in the same line, the compiler knows.

So, why not just remove this requirement? Why not behave like [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [Visual Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic), etc.

**Summary of discussion**

Two examples/instances were missing, and a semi-colon would actually cause a problem.

1.

```
return
 (a+b)
```

This was presented as one of the worst aspects of JavaScript. But, in this scenario, semicolon insertion is a problem for JavaScript, but not
for C++. In C++, you will get another error if `;` insertion is done after return. That is, a missing return value.

2

```
int *y;
int f = 1
*y = 2;
```

For this I guess, there is no better way than to introduce as statement separator, that is, a **semicolon**.

Comment: Python & VB are just like C++, but instead of just having semicolons to separate statements, they use line-breaks, which leads to requirement of line continuation characters.

Comment: **"Later I can fix the warning"** - love this :). I can't count how many such *Later*s I've seen, which were never fixed (not only about programming)

Comment: @Alexander Malakhov - I agree

Comment: @Alexander Just mark it with // TODO Fix warning :)

Comment: @Daniel: That would be perfect solution for missing semicolons. lol :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are many cases where a semicolon is needed.

What if you had:

```
int *y;
int f = 1
*y = 2;
```

This would be parsed as

```
int *y;
int f = 1 * y = 2;
```

So without the semicolons it is ambiguous.

Comment: This isn't ambiguous, it's just wrong. You can't multiply an `int` with a pointer, and a terminal can't be an lvalue.

Comment: There are other examples one could come up with that wouldn't lead to errors.  `int x = y * z--`

Comment: I like this answer more because it seems there is nothing which can be done in syntax to solve this.

Comment: Think that the programmer has made a mistake, and the compiler has noticed. Can the compiler guess that the programmer missed a `;`? What if the programmer missed something else (`*` could fit above)? The compiler knows that you have made a mistake, but it cannot possibly know what you meant to do.

Comment: +1 For illustrating that the compiler can't always determine what you really meant, and in that case there's no point in guessing some of the time.

Answer (score 55):

It's *very* good that the C++ compiler doesn't do this. One of the *worst* aspects of JavaScript is the semicolon insertion. Picture this:

```
return
  (a + b);
```

The C++ compiler will happily continue on the next line as expected, while a language that "inserts" semicolons, like JavaScript, will treat it as "return;" and miss out the "(a + b);".

Instead of rely on compiler error-fixing, make it a habit to use semicolons.

Comment: +1 it is always good programming practice to be as explicit as possible with your intentions- don't rely on your tools to do it for you.

Comment: The Javascript example is the first one that came to my mind as well.

Comment: So why not add a line continuation char like _ as it is in other languages

Comment: @SysAdmin: Then you'd need to add line continuation characters all over the place, and if you forgot them your code would still correctly compile but wouldn't do what you expected it to.

Comment: @SysAdmin Because C++ is not those other languages. It has its very well defined semantics that people can rely on.

Comment: Why should? Thats the same as asking why should there be a semi-colon delimiter in C and C++.

Comment: @Joe Gauterin - do you see line continuation char's all over the place in VB or python? why are they confident that they dont need ;? I would say that the answer given by Jason Williams is more obvious reason

Comment: Moreover, this particular example code wont compile and run because, you will get another error saying "you are not returning any value for this function as the function expects a return int value"

Comment: @Sys: you can omit the return value for `main`.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose - if you put a return statement in main, you will get an error

Comment: @Sys: I double checked, and you are correct, my apologies.  Not returning is the same as returning 0, but `return` is not.

Comment: @SysAdmin: You're not talking about designing a new language with significant whitespace like python - you're talking about retrofitting them to an existing syntax for which they're not suitable.

Comment: @Joe Gauterin - I agree, but I just wanted to say that this scenario presented in this post cannot be compiled for a different reason - i.e function expects an int value as return . if you do ; insertion after return, you will get this error

Comment: C++ does have a line continuation character: \

Comment: This is the answer that made me understand why to add semicolon.

Answer (score 8):

First, this is only a small example; are you sure the compiler can intelligently tell you what's wrong for more complex code?  For *any* piece of code?  Could all compilers intelligently recognize this in the same way, so that a piece of C++ code could be guaranteed portable with missing semicolons?

Second, C++ was created more than a decade ago when computing resources aren't nearly what they are now.  Even today, builds can take a considerable amount of time.  Semicolons help to clearly demarcate different commands (for the user and for the compiler!) and assist both the programmer and the compiler in understanding what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

`;` is for the programmer's convenience. If the line of code is very long then we can press enter and go to second line because we have  `;` for line separator. It is programming conventions. There must be a line separator.

Comment: @Sys: He's right.  C and C++'s syntax requires a statement terminator of some sort.  That's what the other answers are saying.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose - I agree to what you are saying, but I just dont agree that ; is a line seperator and its for programmer's convenience

Answer (score 3):

Having semi-colons (or line breaks, pick one) makes the compiler vastly simpler and error messages more readable.

**But contrary to what other people have said, neither form of delimiters (as an *absolute*) is strictly necessary.**

Consider, for example, Haskell, which doesn’t have either. Even the current version of VB allows line breaks in many places inside a statement, as does Python. Neither requires line continuations in many places.

For example, VB now allows the following code:

```
Dim result = From element in collection
             Where element < threshold
             Select element
```

No statement delimiters, no line continuations, and yet no ambiguities whatsoever.

Theoretically, this could be driven much further. *All* ambiguities can be eliminated (again, look at Haskell) by introducing some rules. But again, this makes the parser much more complicated (it has to be context sensitive in a lot of places, e.g. your `return` example, which cannot be resolved without first knowing the return type of the function). And again, it makes it much harder to output meaningful diagnostics since an erroneous line break could mean any of several things so the compiler cannot know *which error* the user has made, and not even *where* the error was made.

Answer (score 2):

In C programs semicolons are statement terminators, not separators. You might want to read [this fun article](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/the-semicolon-wars/2).

Answer (score 0):

+1 to you both.

The semi-colon is a command line delimiter, unlike VB, python etc. C and C++ ignore white space within lines of code including carriage returns! This was originally because at inception of C computer monitors could only cope with 80 characters of text and as C++ is based on the C specification it followed suit.

I could post up the question "Why must I keep getting errors about missing \ characters in VB when I try and write code over several lines, surely if VB knows of the problem it can insert it?"

Auto insertion as has already been pointed out could be a nightmare, especially on code that wraps onto a second line.

Answer (score 0):

I won't extend much of the need for semi-colon vs line continuation characters, both have advantages and disadvantages and in the end it's a simple language design choice (even though it affects all the users).

I am more worried about the suggestion for the compiler to *fix* the code.

If you have ever seen a marvelous tool (such as... hum let's pick up a `merge` tool) and the way it does its automated work, you would be very glad indeed that the compiler did not modify the code. Ultimately if the compiler knew how to fix the code, then it would mean it knew your intent, and thought transmission has not been implemented yet.

As for the *warning* ? Any programmer worth its salt knows that warnings should be treated as errors (and compilation stopped) so what would be the advantage ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int sdf = 1,df=2;
sdf=1 df =2
```

I think the general problem is that without the semicolon there's no telling what the programmer could have actually have meant (e.g may-be the second line was intended as `sdf = 1 + df - 2;` with serious typos). Something like this might well result from completely arbitrary typos and have any intended meaning, wherefore it might not be such a good idea after all to have the compiler silently "correct" errors.

You may also have noticed that you often get "expected semicolon" where the real problem is not a lack of a semicolon but something completely different instead. Imagine a malformed expression that the compiler could make sense out of by silently going and inserting semicolons.

The semicolon may seem redundant but it is a simple way for the programmer to confirm "yes, that was my intention".

Also, warnings instead of compiler errors are too weak. People compile code with warnings off, ignore warnings they get, and AFAIK the standard never prescribes what the compiler must warn about.