# TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined while using ajax code in submitHandler

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-validate

I m new to validate plugin in jquery...I m trying to use submitHandler for submitting the form after the validation. But i get the error..TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined... i have gone through other answers but found no solution. i get the error on clicking the submit button.

Below is my html code

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../public/assets/js/personal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="personal_form" method="post" action="">
        Registeration ID:<input type="text" id="regid" name="regid" value="<?php echo $regid?>" readonly><br>
        First Name:<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php echo $fname;?>"><br>
        Last Name:<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="<?php echo $lname;?>"><br>
        Gender:<div style="margin:-17px;padding-left:81px">
                    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($gender);$i++):?>
                        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender[]" value="<?php echo $gender[$i]['slno'];?>"> <?php echo $gender[$i]['gender']?>
                    <?php endfor;?>
                </div>
                <br>
        Care of:<div style="margin:-19px;padding-left:81px;"> 
                    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($careof);$i++):?>
                        <input type="radio" id="careof" name="careof[]" value="<?php echo $careof[$i]['slno']?>"> <?php echo $careof[$i]['care_of'];?>
                    <?php endfor;?>
                </div><br>
        Native Place:<input type="text" name="native_place" id="native_place"><br>
        Date of Enrollment:<select id="enroll_year" name="enroll_year">
                                <option value="0">YEAR</option>
                                <?php for($i=1947;$i<=$date;$i++):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                                <?php endfor;?>
                            </select>
                            <select id="enroll_month" name="enroll_month">
                                <option value="0">MONTH</option>
                                <?php for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                                <?php endfor;?>
                            </select>
                            <select id="enroll_date" name="enroll_date"> 
                                <option value="0">DATE</option>
                                <?php for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                                <?php endfor;?>
                            </select><br>
        Enrollment No:<input type="text" name="enroll_no" id="enroll_no" value="<?php echo $data[0]['enroll_no'];?>" ><br>
        Court of Practice:<input type="text" name="court_practice" id="court_practice" value="<?php echo $data[0]['court_practice'];?> "><br>
        Field of Practice:<input type="text" name="field_practice" id="field_practice" value="<?php echo $data[0]['field_practice'];?>"><br>
        Name of the Bar Association:<input type="text" name="name_bar_assoc" id="name_bar_assoc" value="<?php echo $data[0]['bar_council_name']; ?>"><br>
        Designation:<input type="text" name="designation" id="designation"><br>
        Date of Birth:<select id="dob_year" name="dob_year">
                                <option value="0">YEAR</option>
                                <?php for($i=1947;$i<=$date;$i++):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                                <?php endfor;?>
                            </select>
                            <select id="dob_month" name="dob_month">
                                <option value="0">MONTH</option>
                                <?php for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                                <?php endfor;?>
                            </select>
                            <select id="dob_date" name="dob_date"> 
                                <option value="0">DATE</option>
                                <?php for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                                <?php endfor;?>
                            </select><br>
        Blood Group:<input type="text" name="blood_group" id="blood_group"><br>
        Office Address:<input type="text" name="office_addr" id="office_addr"><br>
        Residence Address:<input type="text" name="residence_addr" id="residence_addr" value="<?php echo $data[0]['addr'];?>"><br>
        Mobile No:<input type="text" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" value="<?php echo $data[0]['mobile_no'];?>"><br>
        Office No:<input type="text" name="office_number" id="office_number"><br>
        Residence No:<input type="text" name="residence_number" id="residence_number"><br>
        Email ID:<input type="text" name="email_id" id="email_id" value="<?php echo $data[0]['email_id'];?>"><br>
        Photo:<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo"><br>
        <div id="photo"></div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit_personal" value="Submit">
        <div id="response"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

personal.js is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#personal_form").validate({
        rules:{
            first_name:{
                required:true,
                minlength:5,
                maxlength:32
            },
            last_name:{
                required:true,
                minlength:5,
                maxlength:32
            },
            'gender[]':{
                required:true,

            },
            'careof[]':{
                required:true,

            },
            native_place:{
                required:true
            },
            enroll_year:{
                selectenrollyear:true
            },
            enroll_month:{
                selectenrollmonth:true
            },
            enroll_date:{
                selectenrolldate:true
            },
            enroll_no:
            {
                required:true
            },
            court_practice:
            {
                required:true
            },
            field_practice:
            {
                required:true
            },
            name_bar_assoc:
            {
                required:true
            },
            designation:
            {
                required:true
            },
            dob_year:
            {
                selectdobyear:true
            },
            dob_month:
            {
                selectdobmonth:true
            },
            dob_date:
            {
                selectdobdate:true
            },
            blood_group:
            {
                required:true
            },
            office_addr:
            {
                required:true
            },
            residence_addr:
            {
                required:true
            },
            mobile_number:
            {
                required:true,
                mobilecheck:true
            },
            office_number:
            {
                required:true
            },
            residence_number:
            {
                required:true
            },
            email_id:
            {
                required:true,
                email:true
            },
            photo:
            {
                required:true,
                accept: "image/*"
            }
        },
        messages:{
            first_name:{
                minlength: "First name should be atleast 5 characters",
                maxlength: "First name should not be more than 32 characters"
            },
            last_name:{
                minlength: "Last name should be atleast 5 characters",
                maxlength: "Last name should not be more than 32 characters"
            },
            gender:{
                required:"Please select a gender"
            },
            careof:{
                required:"Please select careof"
            },
            native_place:{
                required:"Please enter your native place"
            },
            enroll_no:
            {
                required:"Please enter your enrollment number"
            },
            court_practice:
            {
                required:"Please enter the court of practice"
            },
            filed_practice:
            {
                required:"Please enter the field of practice"
            },
            name_bar_assoc:
            {
                required:"Please enter the name of bar association"
            },
            designation:
            {
                required:"Please enter your designation"
            },

            blood_group:
            {
                required:"Please enter your blood group"
            },
            office_addr:
            {
                required:"Please fill your office address seperated by comma"
            },
            residence_addr:
            {
                required:"Please fill your residence address seperated by comma"
            },
            mobile_number:
            {
                required:"Please fill your mobile number"
            },
            office_number:
            {
                required:"Please fill your office number"
            },
            residence_number:
            {
                required:"Please fill your residence number"
            },
            email_id:
            {
                required:"Please fill your email id",
                email:"The email should be in the form sample@example.com"
            },
            photo:
            {
                required:"Please upload your photo",
                accept:"Image files only"
            }
        },
        submitHandler:function(form){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "assets/js/personal.php",
                data: form.serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectenrollyear',function (value) {
        return (value != 0);
    }, "Select the enrollment year");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectenrollmonth',function (value) {
        return (value != 0);
    }, "Select the enrollment month");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectenrolldate',function (value) {
        return (value != 0);
    }, "Select the enrollment date");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectdobyear',function (value) {
        return (value != 0);
    },"Select the year");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectdobmonth',function (value) {
        return (value != 0);
    },"Select the month");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectdobdate',function (value) {
        return (value != 0);
    },"Select the date");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('mobilecheck',function (value){
        if(value.length != 9)
            return value;
    },"Mobile number should be of 10 digits");

});



Personal .php is as follows
<?php
    echo $_POST["regid"];
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Could u provide a fiddle mate..??

Comment: it includes some php also.....

Comment: Try copying  the form html from the browser console

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fpbqhvym/

Comment: Should be `data: $(form).serialize()` within your `ajax()`.

Comment: **FYI:  You do not need all those custom methods for your `select` element validation!**  Simply change `value="0"` into `value=""` on the first `option` of every `select`, and apply the standard `required` rule.

Comment: Please only show the ***rendered*** HTML, not the PHP.  You're also mixing Allman with K & R code indentation style.  One could argue that you should [not use Allman with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11247328/594235) because JS has "automatic semicolon insertion".  Regardless, it's sloppy when your code doesn't stick to one style.

Comment: As long as you include jQuery and the Validate plugin to your jsFiddle, it works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/fpbqhvym/1/