# jQuery Validate over two fields (checkbox and text field)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 fields

```
<input type="text" name="num_gals" placeholder="Num of Gallons">
<input type="checkbox" value="TRUE"  name="full_tank">Full Tank?
```

I am using jquery-validation to enforce the following rule.
Either the input field "num_gals" should have a non-zero value or the "full_tank" checkbox should be checked.

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
rules:
{
    num_gals:   
    {
        required: function() 
        {
            if ($('.full_tank').val(':checked')) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    },
    full_tank:
    {
        required: function() 
        {
            if ($('.num_gals').val() == '') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
},

messages:
{
    num_gals:
    {
        required: 'Provide Num Gals or Check Full Tank'
    },
    full_tank:
    {
        required: 'Provide Num Gals or Check Full Tank'
    }
}
```

Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following mistakes...

1. `$('.full_tank')` is looking for a **`class`** called `full_tank` and in this case, there is no such `class`.  You need to select the **`name`** attribute with `$('input[name="full_tank"]')`.  Do the same for your other selector.
2. `.val(':checked')` is looking for a **value** of `:checked` and there is no such thing.  To determine if it **IS** checked, use [jQuery `.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
3. `.val() == ''` works ok, but it can be replaced with [`.is(':blank')`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/selectors/#:blank-selector), which also matches a field filled with whitespace characters thanks to the plugin's custom `:blank` selector.

Please review:  [jQuery Selector Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [jQuery Validate Selector Reference](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/selectors).

---

Since your conditional function simply returns a boolean based on the result of a boolean, you can shorten it by just putting a `return` in front of the conditional.

```
rules: {
    num_gals: {
        required: function() {
            return ! ($('input[name="full_tank"]').is(':checked'));
        }
    },
    full_tank: {
        required: function() {
            return ($('input[name="num_gals"]').is(':blank'));
        }
    }
},
```

BTW: Your code is JavaScript, so [it's best to avoid Allman code style, typically used with PHP, because JavaScript automatically inserts semicolons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11247328/594235).

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/r4arpshm/**

Comment: Thanks @Sparky. Really appreciate the detailed answer and explanation. Also many thanks for the tip on avoiding Allman style of coding.

Comment: Do you know how to construct a rule such that both fields cant be allowed at the same time. i.e. num_gals cant be "non_blank" and full_tank cant be "checked" at the same time?

Comment: @rogerb, you'll have to create a custom rule using the `.addMethod()` method. See docs:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
if ($('.full_tank').is(':checked')) {
```

Comment: The `$('.full_tank')` selector matches nothing in the OP's markup, since the OP is trying to use a `class` selector to grab the element by `name`.