# Validate dynamic radio buttons jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-validate

**Problem:** I can´t validate dynamically created radio buttons.

**Question:** how do I use jQuery to validate the radio buttons?

Is it possible to customise the jQuery to validate dynamically created radio buttons?

Any suggestions?

**HTML and PHP from my form**

```
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name='radnummer_varde[<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>]' value='1' <?php if (($hamta_formaga['radnummer_varde'] == '1')) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>>
    <i class="rounded-x"></i>Prövas
</label>

<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name='radnummer_varde[<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>]' value='0' <?php if (($hamta_formaga['radnummer_varde'] == '0')) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>>
    <i class="rounded-x"></i>Prövas ej
</label>
```

`echo $kk['radnummer']` is numeric.

**Validation via JS**

```
var AbbRedigeraForm = function () {

    return {        

        initAbbRedigeraForm: function () {
            // Validation
            $("#redigera_abb").validate({
                // Regler för validation
                rules:
                {
                    'radnummer_varde[]':
                    {
                        required: true                      
                    },
                    aktiv:
                    {
                        required: true                      
                    },
                    arbetsomrade:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8,
                        maxlength: 30
                    },
                    syfte:
                    {
                        required: true                      
                    },
                    overgripande_mal:
                    {
                        required: true                      
                    },
                    undervisning:
                    {
                        required: true
                    },
                    redovisningsform:
                    {
                        required: true
                    },

                },

                // Messages for form validation
                messages:
                {
                    radnummer_varde:
                    {
                        required: 'Du måste ange detta.'                        
                    },
                    arbetsomrade:
                    {
                        required: 'Skriv en rubrik för arbetsområdet.'
                    },
                    syfte:
                    {
                        required: 'Skriv ett syfte.'                        
                    },
                    overgripande_mal:
                    {
                        required: 'Du måste ange övergripande mål.'
                    },
                    undervisning:
                    {
                        required: 'Du måste skriva något om undervisningen.'
                    },
                    redovisningsform:
                    {
                        required: 'Du måste skriva något om redovisning.'
                    },                  
                },      
                // Do not change code below
                errorPlacement: function(error, element)
                {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                }
            });
        }

    };

}();
```

**EDIT 2015-03-27:**

Option 2

```
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name='radnummer_varde[<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>]' value='1' <?php if (($hamta_formaga['radnummer_varde'] == '1')) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>>
    <i class="rounded-x"></i>Prövas
</label>

<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name='radnummer_varde[<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>]' value='0' <?php if (($hamta_formaga['radnummer_varde'] == '0')) echo 'checked="checked" '; ?>>
    <i class="rounded-x"></i>Prövas ej
</label>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#redigera_abb').validate({});                                
    $('[name="radnummer_varde[<?php echo $kk['radnummer'];?>]"]').rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "At least one option needed."
        }
    }); 
    });                             
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

> "Is it possible to customise the jQuery to validate dynamically created radio buttons?"

Yes, this is no different than adding validation to any dynamically created element.

First, let's examine this part of your code...

```
var AbbRedigeraForm = function () {

    return {        

        initAbbRedigeraForm: function () {
            // Validation
            $("#redigera_abb").validate({
                // Regler för validation
                rules:
                {
                    'radnummer_varde[]':
                    {
                        required: true                      
                    },
                    ....
```

1. You would not normally put `.validate()` inside of a function.  It's **not** the testing method... `.validate()` is the ***initialization*** method.  Therefore, **`.validate()` only goes inside a DOM ready handler where it's called one time** to initialize the plugin on your form.  Otherwise, validation is not ready when you need it and/or the `.validate()` method is called repeatedly.
2. You cannot declare a rule within the `rules` option of `.validate()` if you do not have the **exact** `name` of the element.  Since `radnummer_varde[]` is not really the actual `name`, this rule declaration does nothing.
3. Minor point, but you should never use Allman style code formatting in JavaScript.  Why?  Because [JavaScript uses "Automatic Semicolon Insertion"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11247362/594235).  It also makes the code a little harder to read for people that are familiar with JavaScript's more typical 1TBS format.

---

Solutions for dynamically created elements...

**OPTION 1:**  Simply include the rule declaration inline with the element, *instead of* using the `rules` option within `.validate()`.  For the `required` rule, you can either use a `class` or the HTML 5 `required` attribute as follows...

```
<input type="radio" name='radnummer_varde[1]' class="required" ...
```

OR

```
<input type="radio" name='radnummer_varde[1]' required="required" ...
```

There are limitations as certain kinds of complex rules need parameters which cannot be set inline.  That's where option 2 would be needed.

**OPTION 2:**  Use the [plugin's `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) immediately *after* you've dynamically created the input elements.  *(You have not shown how these elements are "dynamically" created.)*

```
// your code that dynamically creates the element

// declare the rule on the new element
$('[name="radnummer_varde[1]"]').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    messages: { // optional
        required: "custom message"
    }
});
```

**OPTION 3:** Your elements are not really created "dynamically", but you do not know the exact `name` in advance.  Use a "starts with" selector to grab all of these elements and a jQuery `.each()` to apply the method to all elements.

```
$('[name^="radnummer_varde"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: { // optional
            required: "custom message"
        }
    });
});
```

**NOTES**:

1. NO MATTER how you declare the rules, every input **must** contain a `name` attribute.
2. Usage of `.rules()` does not negate the usage of the `.validate()` method.  You must have already called `.validate()` on the form to initialize the plugin before you can call `.rules()`.
3. If the selector attached to `.rules()` targets a group of elements at once, then you must use a jQuery `.each()` function or the plugin will only use the first matched element.

---

> "how do I use jQuery to validate the radio buttons?"

I noticed that your HTML for the radio button might contain `checked="checked"` under certain conditions.  Just be aware that if the radio button loads into the page as checked, then there is nothing for validation to do, because the `required` rule is already satisfied.

Comment: First of all: thank you.

Option 1 does the job but of curiosity I want to try the other options too. Option 2 or option 3 doesn't work out as intended. No validation is done. See my edited answer above.

Comment: @Per76, there is nothing wrong with the code you've posted in your edit.  You'll have to use your browser to inspect the code as it's rendered in the browser source.  The `name` is probably not being rendered as you expect... something doesn't match up.  In other words, we're working on a JavaScript issue here, so we do not really care about any of the PHP.

Comment: @Per76, also, I have no context for that code chunk.  If you have not fired `.validate()` when you run the `.rules('add')` method, it's going to fail, probably with console errors.

Comment: Sorry. But I'm a bit lost regarding JavaScript (as you can see). How (and where) do I fire of the .validate() ? It seems as .rules('add') doesn´t run at all and no console errors.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to add the "dynamic" rule to existing validate function (as shown above)? 

The rest of the validation (as shown in initAbbRedigeraForm:) works great. I'm (nearly) a complete noob regarding JavaScript. How do I add rules to that function?

Comment: @Per76, how are you adding "dynamic" elements to the form?  PHP creates the page when it's loaded into the browser... that is NOT considered "dynamic".  If option 1 has solved the problem, why are you still struggling with this?

Comment: Quote @Per76:  *"Do you think it's possible to add the "dynamic" rule to existing validate function"* ~ Yes, that is what my entire answer is showing, how to dynamically add rules.  If it's not working for you, the reason is not apparent by what you've shown.  But again, JavaScript does not care about PHP... we only need to see what is ***rendered*** in the browser source code to verify that it's constructed properly.