# Validaton in jquery boostrap modal, dont work correctly. I have press twice the button submit that happen the validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4, jquery-validate

[image]I have my boostrap modal with the laravel´s framework. When I press the event button. Dont happened nothing, I have press the submit button twice for that the validation happened

I don't get the validation in my language format. What is predefined in validation with `messages:{}`

```
@section('modal_body')
      @if($errors->any())
        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                {{ $error }} <br/>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        @endif
    {{ Form::open(array('id' =>'formuser-create', 'role' => 'form', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('user', 'Nombre de usuario', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::text('user','', array('placeholder' => 'Introduce la contraseña...', 'class' => 'form-control input-md')) }} 
                    <div id="user_error"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('password', 'Contraseña', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::password('password','', array('placeholder' => 'Introduce la contraseña...', 'class' => 'form-control input-md')) }}
                    <div id="password_error"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirmar constraseña', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::password('password_confirmation','', array('placeholder' => 'Vuelve a introducir la contraseña...', 'class' => 'form-control input-md')) }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('email', 'Email', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::text('email','', array('placeholder' => 'Introduce el email...', 'class' => 'form-control input-md')) }} 
                    <div id="email_error"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('es_admin', '¿Es administrador?', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) }}
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    {{ Form::checkbox('es_admin','1') }}
                </div>
            </div>

@stop
@section('modal_footer')
<div class='form-group text-center' id='editor-actions'>
    {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) }} 
    {{ Form::reset('Limpiar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}  
</div>
@stop
```

I've got press twice the button for that happen the validation in the client.

I call with jQuery Validate

My jQuery is:

```
$("document").ready(function()
{
   $("#formuser-create").submit(function()
   {

      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      $("#formuser-create").validate({
        rules:{
            user: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 3,
              maxlength: 10
            },
            password: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 4,
              maxlength: 8
            },
            password_confirmation: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 4,
              maxlength: 8,
              equalTo: "password"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email:true
            },
            messages: {
                user: {
                    required: "El campo usuario no puede quedar vacio",
                    minlength: "El mínimo permito son 3 caracteres",
                    maxlength: "El máximo permitido 10 caracteres"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "El campo password no puede quedar vacio",
                    minlength: "El mínimo permitido es de 4 caracteres ",
                    maxlength: "El máximo permitido es de 8 caracteres"
                },
                password_confirmation: {
                    required: "El campo no puede quedar vacio",
                    minlength: "El mínimo permitido es de 4 caracteres ",
                    maxlength: "El máximo permitido  de 8 caracteres"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "El campo email no puede quedar vacio",
                    email: "Debe ser un email valido"
                }
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function()
        {
             $.ajax({
                url: 'users/create',
                dataType:'json',
                data: form.serialize(),
                type: "POST", 
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response.success)
                    {
                        $("#box-modal").modal('hide');
                        window.location.href = "/users";
                    }
                    else(response.error)
                    {
                        $.each(response.errors, function( index, value ) {
                        var errorDiv = "#"+index+"_error";
                        $(errorDiv).addClass('required');
                        $(errorDiv).empty().append(value);
                        });
                        $("#successMessage").empty();
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus)
                {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                }
            });

        }

    });


   }); 
});
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Please, instead of the server-side code from your framework, show us the ***rendered*** HTML markup as seen by the browser.  (View source) JavaScript does not care about your framework, only what's ultimately constructed in the browser's DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've got press twice the button for that happen the validation in the client.

```
$("document").ready(function() 
{

   $("#formuser-create").submit(function()
   {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);
      $("#formuser-create").validate({  // <- INITIALIZE PLUGIN
          ....
```

Having to click twice is caused by putting the `.validate()` method inside of a `.submit()` handler function.  The `.validate()` method is only used for *initializing* the plugin on your form, so the plugin is not ready to do anything when you click the first time.

The `.validate()` method only belongs inside of the DOM ready event handler.  Once properly initialized, the `click` of the button is captured automatically.

```
$("document").ready(function() {  // <- DOM ready event

      $("#formuser-create").validate({  // <- INITIALIZE PLUGIN
          ....
```

---

> I don't get the validation in my language format. What is predefined in validation with `messages:{}`

```
$("#formuser-create").validate({
    rules: {
        user: {
            required: true,
            ....
        },
        ....
        messages: { // <- you've put 'messages' inside of 'rules' (wrong)
            ....     
        }
    },
    submitHandler
        ....
```

That's because you've put the `messages` option inside the `rules` option where it is ignored.  `rules` and `messages` are *siblings* of each other, therefore `messages` does not belong inside of `rules`.

It should look like this...

```
$("#formuser-create").validate({
    rules:{
        user: {
            required: true,
            ....
        },
        ....
    },
    messages: {
        user: {
            required:  "El campo usuario no puede quedar vacio",
            ....
        },
        ....
    },
    submitHandler
        ....
```

---

You should also not use the Allman style of code formatting in JavaScript.  Stick with 1TBS.

See:  [Dangerous implications of Allman style in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11247328/594235)

Comment: you solution work but the other question is: because it didn´t show the predefinided messages. example messages: {
                user: {
                    required: "El campo usuario no puede quedar vacio",
                    minlength: "El mínimo permito son 3 caracteres",
                    maxlength: "El máximo permitido 10 caracteres"
                },