# Node/Javascript with Revealing Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am playing around with node/javascript. This is just a simple code, logic is not important just playing with the EventEmitter.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong in terms of code not the logic.

Thanks for the help.

```
  var emitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var http = require('http');


function github()
{
    var emitterInstance = new emitter();

    this.getEmitter = function()
    {
        console.log('returning the emitterInstance');
        return emitterInstance;
    };

    this.getData  = function()
    {
          http.get("https://api.github.com/users/loneshark99/gists", function(error,resp)
          {
                if(error)
                {
                    console.log('Error occured!');
                }
                else
                {
                    emitterInstance.emit('dataReceived');
                }
          });
    };

    return {
    emt : getEmitter,
        getData : getData
    };
}

var g = new github();
g.emt().on("dataReceived", function() { console.log('data received from github')})
g.getData();
```

Error is :

```
D:\test.js:33
        getData : getData
                ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Answer :: This works

```
var emitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var http = require('http');


function github()
{
    var emitterInstance = new emitter();

    this.getEmitter = function()
    {
         console.log('returning the emitterInstance');
         return emitterInstance;
    };

    this.getData  = function()
    {
           http.get("http://pluralsight.com", function(resp)
           {
                emitterInstance.emit('dataReceived');
           });
    };


    var obj =  { emt : getEmitter, getData : getData };

    return obj;
}

var g = github();
console.log(g);
g.emt().on("dataReceived", function() { console.log('data received from github')})
g.getData();
```

Comment: What makes you think it is wrong? what isn't working?

Comment: Typo? `g.getEmitter.On` should be `g.emt.On`

Comment: @PSL corrected that but, that's not the issue

Comment: @Kevin B, I don't know that's why I posted this question

Comment: @Ben you've basically said "I have this code, what's wrong with it?" Obviously something is wrong with it, otherwise you wouldn't be posting this question. What is it doing that makes it... "wrong". is it throwing an error? producing unexpected results? producing no results? (no results would likely mean you haven't done enough debugging..)

Comment: @Kevin B added the error

Comment: @Ben why do you need a `return {...}` when you are already attaching the functions to the object instance. `getData != this.getData`

Comment: @PSL I was trying to use the revealing module pattern to do the Public/Private, in this case everything is public but I was just trying to use that pattern

Comment: Please stop to constantly change the code in your question (except for minor typos that are unrelated to the subject), it invalidates the answers. If you've got a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks Everyone! appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

> ```
> var emitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
> ```

I would recommend to follow JavaScript naming conventions, and capitalise constructor names. `Emitter` it should be.

> ```
> this.getEmitter = function() {
> ```

Your function seems to be supposed to be a factory, not a constructor function. For the revealing module pattern, you use local declarations for your functions and variables, instead of attaching properties to `this`. You just return an object literal with the exported values in the end.

> ```
> emitterInstance.emit('dataReceived');
> ```

Since the purpose of your code seems to be that data can be received, you should actually propagate the received data. Hand it back to your controller by passing the `resp` as an argument to the emitted event. Make this a `var getEmitter = function() {`, or even better a `function getEmitter() {`.

> ```
> return 
> {
> ```

ASI will hit you here. Hit you hard. [Don't use Allman bracket style in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11247328/1048572), but put your braces on the same line.

> ```
> emt : getEmitter,
> ```

This doesn't match your invocation. Should the method name really be `emt`?

> ```
> new github();
> ```

As said above, `github` is a factory function that does return an object, not a constructor that creates instances which inherit from a prototype. Don't use `new` here, just call the function.

> ```
> g.getEmitter.On
> ```

To get your event emitter instance, you will need to call your method. And `On` should be `on`.

Comment: I fixed the typo for on. and thanks for the conventions. appreciate it

Comment: Ah, thanks for including an error message in the question. That error seems to be appropriate for the line-break case, as `emt:` is a valid label but `getData` after a comma is no more. If you have fixed the ASI, I cannot explain this any more, make sure that you properly saved your file and node doesn't cache the module source.

Comment: I think you were correct, when I added the return to one line returned the object, it worked.  Seems fishy to me, why one works and not the other.

Comment: That's why I have linked that other question for you :-) Also have a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ASI+return+%5Bjavascript%5D) if you need further reading.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `new github()` returns `this`. Try:

```
var g = github();
```

I would double check and make sure `emitter` is meant to be newed up.

Answer (score 0):

`getEmitter` should be `getEmitter()`, but even doing that would be calling it out of scope. You could assign those functions to the prototype of `github` like so:

```
this.getEmitter = function() {
  console.log('returning the emitterInstance');
  return emitterInstance;
};
```

Also, `On` should be `on`.

The same would need to be done to the `g.getData()` call.

An alternative would be to define it like:

`github.prototype.getEmitter = function() { ... }`

Comment: I understand that it can be done with prototype or this keyword. I am trying to understand what is wrong in the code.

Comment: `g.getEmitter` is not defined. `g.getData` is not defined.

Comment: Exactly why is my question, wont they get wrapped

Comment: If you `console.log(g)` you should get undefined. Move the opening curly brace onto the same line as return