# jQuery validation plugin is validating only specific form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying basic client-side form validation using jQuery validation plugin.I have a basic sign up form, if  I click on a button to create an account with all fields empty(just for testing), I am getting nice error messages as expected on all form fields **except** for only one field for inputting cellphone number. I have downloaded the code from the internet and this is the only field I have added.I am using Xampp, Things became even more strange after I moved all files to another computer and try to test the same validation, Guess what?  **it's no longer working as expected for all fields**. This problem has been frying my brains, any help I will be grateful below is the code

**HTML**

```
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2><hr />

        <div id="error">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="user_name" id="user_name" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="user_email" id="user_email" />
            <span id="check-e"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cellphone" name="user_cellphone" id="user_cellphone" />
        </div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype Password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" />
        </div>
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-save" id="btn-submit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account
            </button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

**JS**

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
/* validation */
$("#register-form").validate({
    rules:
    {
        user_name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        user_cellphone: {
            required: true,
            number: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8,
            maxlength: 15
        },
        cpassword: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: '#password'
        },
        user_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages:
    {
        user_name: "Enter a Valid Username",
        user_cellphone:{
            required: "Provide a phone number",
            number: "Phone Needs To Be a number"
        },
        password:{
            required: "Provide a Password",
            minlength: "Password Needs To Be Minimum of 8 Characters"
        },
        user_email: "Enter a Valid Email",
        cpassword:{
            required: "Retype Your Password",
            equalTo: "Password Mismatch! Retype"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: submitForm
});
/* validation */
/* form submit */
function submitForm()
{
    var data = $("#register-form").serialize();

    $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'register.php',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; sending ...');
        },
        success :  function(data)
        {
            if(data==1){

                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){


                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Sorry email already taken !</div>');

                    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                });

            }
            else if(data=="registered")
            {

                $("#btn-submit").html('Signing Up');
                setTimeout('$(".form-signin").fadeOut(500, function(){ $(".signin-form").load("successreg.php"); }); ',5000);

            }
            else{

                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){

                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+data+' !</div>');

                    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                });

            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
/* form submit */
```

Below is a snapshot of the form, I cant really figure out where is the problem.
[image: form with field for cellphone not showing errors]

Comment: What is `submitHandler: submitForm` doing?  I don't see any `submitForm` function anyplace in your code.

Comment: I thought my question will be too long,I have edited my question to include the code for handling form submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the `number` rule, but your corresponding message is assigned to the `minlength` rule...

```
rules: {
    user_cellphone: {
        required: true,
        number: true
    },
    ....
},
messages: {
    user_cellphone: {
        required: "Provide a phone number",
        minlength: "Phone Needs To Be a number"
    },
    ....
```

And `document` should **not** be in quotes...

```
$(document).ready(function() {...
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/bh5g0wfe/

**Side note**:  You may want to read this too...

[Dangerous implications of Allman style in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247328/dangerous-implications-of-allman-style-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you Sparky for pointing that out. I changed from `minlength` to `number` but  still it's not working.I am checking the link you have provided.If there is another way of validating you can suggest I will be grateful.

Comment: @Ngenazy, I don't know what else to tell you.  Your code is working fine in my demo, and I'd always recommend jQuery Validate.