# Jquery validate not working for input with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Jquery validate works fine for other inputs, but for those with datepickers initialized, it is not updating error messages even though valid input is entered. Also I figured out that if the value inside the element is selected (focused) with valid input and focused out of the element, the error message vanishes, which is why I tried to $(element).select(), It worked but it had drawbacks...

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="date_of_birth" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Date of Birth <span class="input-required">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-7">
          <div class='input-group date' id='date_of_birth'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control dateField" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" id="date_of_birth_field" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"value=""/>
              <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span>
          </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

This is how datePicker initialized, if it helps..

```
$('#date_of_birth').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    language: 'en',
    maxDate: new Date,
    icons: {
        time: "fa fa-clock-o",
        date: "fa fa-calendar",
        up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
        down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
    }
});
```

Here is a validation script:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorElement: 'span',
    focusInvalid: true,
    ignore: ":hidden",
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass)
    {

      var fieldtype = ($(element).hasClass('dateField') ? 'dateField' : 'normal');
      switch(fieldtype)
      {
        case "dateField":
          $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
          // $(element).select();
          break;
        default:
          $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
          break;
      }

    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass)
    {
      if($(element).hasClass('select2-offscreen'))
      {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $(element).next('span').css({display: "none"});
      }

      else
      {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
      }   
    },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            var fieldtype = ($(element).hasClass('dateField') ? 'dateField' : 'normal');

            switch (fieldtype) {
                case "dateField":
                    error.appendTo(element.parent().parent());
                    break;
                default:
                    error.appendTo(element.parent());
                    break;
            }
        }
  });
$('#employee-form').validate(
  {
    rules: {
            date_of_birth: {
                gbdDate: true,
                required: true
            }
           },
    messages: {
            date_of_birth: "Please enter valid date";
              }
  });
```

I know this is all long and boring, but I couldn't make it run in JSfiddle... Please some one help me with this..

Comment: Allman style code format for JavaScript is not standard a practice; nor is it a good practice:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11247362/594235

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my answer : [SparkBox](https://seesparkbox.com/foundry/validating_the_jquery_ui_datepicker)

```
$('.dateField').datepicker({
    onClose: function()
     {
        $(this).valid();
     }
});
```

This solved it...

Comment: Thank you! This solved it for me. I was trying with $("#searchForm").validate(); to validate the whole form and it was not working.